# LINQ filtering based on preview filter

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I want to use LINQ, but it depends on a few factors

```
If cbo1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
'LINQ filter
End If

If me.cbo2SelectedIndex > -1 Then
'Filtering the LINQ again with data from the first combobox...
End If
```

Do I have to rewrite the whole LINQ or is there another way

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what this is supposed to do, please? It’s very difficult to tell from that vague snippet of code…

Comment: Well, if I would use the dataview (dv) then I could use dv.Filter("...")
Without having to write dim dv as new dataview(dattable1, "..", "ID")

Cause if you need to "rewrite" the LINQ, it's gonna be much coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Declare your variable at the top using the `IQueryable` type that would be used by the different sections, and then selectively apply the filter based on your logic.

```
Dim query = InitializeQuery() ' returns type IQueryable(Of YourCustomClass)

If cbo1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
  'LINQ filter
  query = from x in query 
          where x.Condition1 = cbo1.SelectedValue 
          select x
End If

If me.cbo2SelectedIndex > -1 Then
  'Filtering the LINQ again with data from the first combobox...
  query = from x in query 
          where x.Condition2 = cbo2SelectedIndex.SelectedValue 
          select x
End If
```

The type of `query` stays the same throughout. The only thing that changes in each branch is its definition.